# SQL Server Compact Edition - Obtain create script

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-ce

I normally live in a MySQL world where I can use the

```
SHOW CREATE TABLE <tablename>
```

syntax to get the create script of a given table.

I'm working with a legacy SQL Server CE 3.5 database and need to get the create script for all of the tables so I can move them into another database which will be created by my application.

Is there any equivalent to the MySQL functionality that would allow me to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

YOu can use my free tool to to script object creation and data statements from a SQL Compact database - http://sqlcetoolbox.codeplex.com